# How to learn finance?

Tags: finance, learning

I have a background in programming of about 6 years. Now I decided to learn finance and trading as well. How can I get my foot in the door in that area?

Comment: This site is dedicated to quantitative finance itself, and career advice are off-topic here.

Comment: @SRKX, the sky is blue.

Answer (score 1):

Asking a lot of questions... It really depends on what area of finance you are interested in (I.e. bonds, stocks, research, valuation, capital budgeting,etc.) but as they say "experience is the best teacher" , so there is nothing better than going out there and getting your hands dirty